# MySQL, pooling and Bluebird promises

Tags: mysql, node.js, promise, bluebird

I'm trying to set up a Promise using a MySQL pool. My 'db.js' module is like this:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var Promise = require('bluebird');

Promise.promisifyAll(require('mysql/lib/Connection').prototype);
Promise.promisifyAll(require('mysql/lib/Pool').prototype);

function db(config) {
  this.pool = mysql.createPool(config);
}

db.prototype.query = function(query) {
  return this.pool.getConnectionAsync()
    .then((db) => {
      return db.queryAsync(query).then(function(arg) {
        db.release();
        try {
          return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arg));
        }
        catch(e) {
          throw e;
        }
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      db.release();
      throw err;
    });
}

module.exports = db;
```

When I want to perform a query, I do as follow:

```
var _db = require('./db');
var db = new _db(config.get('db'));
db.query('select * from users')
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Is the scheme I'm using correct? Do I release properly the connections? Is the synchronous try/catch inside the queryAsync performing right? Should I return the promises catch with a throw?

I ask this all because all the examples I'm finding differs from mine, however my code seems right to me! So, is my code right or am I missing something important? It seems to be so little code for such a complicated task!

Comment: The try catch block is not needed. getConnection is not needed. the pool should handle that by itself. (its only needed if you want to perform multiple queries in the same transaction)

Comment: note that in your `.catch` `db` is not the connection. So it does not have a `release` method.

Comment: @Roland Starke, ok I understand the catch/release and that the try/catch block is not needed. So, should I do this.pool.queryAsync() to perform the query? And what about the throw, is that right in a promise?

Comment: Yes throwing in a catch or then callback, makes sense. Your promise will be rejected and you can chain another catch.